# Sedna: Add XML file to document

Tags: xml, file, load, sedna

I am running a simple Sedna database but have a small issue.
I have multiple XML files that I want to add all to the same document. The files all follow the same schema.

```
LOAD "1.xml" "mydoc"&
LOAD "2.xml" "mydoc"&
LOAD "3.xml" "mydoc"
```

But I get the following error

```
SEDNA Message: ERROR SE2001
Document with the same name already exists.
Details: tariffs
```

How can I go about adding each file to the existing document without removing the existing contents of the document? Is this possible?

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Ilya [answered](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.sedna/2006) you in the Sedna discussion list: there is no way to load many xml files into one document.
But perhaps what you want is collection. You can create a collection by:

```
 CREATE COLLECTION "mycol"&
 LOAD "1.xml" "1" "mycol"&
 LOAD "2.xml" "2" "mycol"&
```

After that collection may be queried just like document:

```
collection('mycol')//some-nodes&
```

Please read Sedna documentation (especially this:
http://modis.ispras.ru/sedna/c-samples.html#loadcol) for more information on
collections.